# Call a fixture in other fixture and use the second fixture in test

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have this situation:

conftest.py

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def get_table_x():
    table_x = ['one', 'two', 'three'] #here is a function call that return the table
    return table_x

@pytest.fixture
def get_table_y():
    table_y = ['one', 'two', 'three'] #here is a function call that return the table
    return table_y

@pytest.fixture(params=get_table_x) #here I receive: "TypeErrorL 'function' object is not iterable"
def get_element(request):
    element = request.param
    yield element
```

test_file.py

```
import pytest

def test_len_lists(get_table_x, get_table_y):
    assert len(get_table_x) == len(get_table_y) #this works fine

@pytest.mark.parametrize('item', get_element): #here, "get_element" is not visible
def test_items_name(item, get_table_y) # I need to run this test for each item
    assert item in get_table_y
```

As a mention, I need to generate elements from first list in "get_element" fixture also to use each element as input for other fixture.
Is this approach possible in pytest?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right lines looking at SeanH's description here

https://www.seanh.cc/2017/02/12/advanced-fixtures/#a-fixture-can-use-multiple-other-fixtures

> the test uses the controller fixture, which uses the user and pyramid_request fixtures, so the test indirectly uses the user and pyramid_request fixtures as well.